# How to implement Google Maps to search by street name?

Tags: php, google-maps

I wonder whether it is possible to make a Google Maps search engine on your own web site to search just by streets (visitor typing the street name and then hit search) and the search engine automatically adds the city name and the state name that I added?

So the search is actually only working for a city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the geocoding functions in the api, take a look here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/